# Android Room Error: Fields annotated with @Relation must be a List or Set

Tags: android, android-room

I want to use One to One relationship in room that available from version 2.2.0-alpha1.
My current room version 2.2.5 and I get an error:

```
error: Fields annotated with @Relation must be a List or Set.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is change in android name since androidx.

Make sure to use androidx instead of arch(deprecated) in app

```
def room_version = "2.2.5"

implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```