# Room Database Get last chat message when loading chats

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, android-room

I'm developing a chat application where messages are being saved in offline room database

I have two tables

```
Contact
   - contact_id
   - contact_name
   - about

ChatMessage
   - contact_id
   - content
   - received_at
```

On chats screen I'm displaying recent chats by querying on contacts table
But i'm trying to show recent chats so better way is to query ChatMessage table get unique recent messages and also retrieve the contact information like name

So i've implemented a very poor method (possibly the worst) which includes

> 1.Fetch all chat messages

> 2.Group by contact_id with most recent chat

> 3.In for loop query and fetch the contact row and append the name to main object list

> 4.Display the list in recycler view

I was wondering if there is any better way of doing this

I think relations or joins can help but i'm unaware of them or their implementation in room DB

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check next approach in Java (but the idea is the same for Kotlin):

1. Add `message_id` (Primary Key) to your `ChatMessage` entity.
2. In addition to `Contact` and `ChatMessage` entities add one more class `LastMessages` (not entity, just POJO):

```
public class LastMessage {

    @Embedded
    public ChatMessage lastMessage;

    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "contact_id",
        entityColumn = "contact_id"
    )
    public Contact contact; 

}
```

3. add next method to your dao:

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM chat_message AS cm JOIN (SELECT contact_id, max(received_at) AS received_at FROM chat_message GROUP BY contact_id) AS cm_last ON cm_last.contact_id = cm.contact_id AND cm_last.received_at = cm.received_at")
public List<LastMessage> getLastMessages();
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be GROUP BY contact_id instead of message_id ?

Comment: Also isn't  "ON cm_last.message_id = cm.message_id"  enough? Why are we using "AND cm_last.received_at = cm.received_at"?

Comment: `Shouldn't it be GROUP BY contact_id instead of message_id` - yes, you're right. updated my answer. But as for `cm_last.received_at = cm.received_at` you need this to get only one last message

Comment: I'm getting compile time error implementing, error: Fields annotated with @Relation must be a List or Set.

Comment: I don't see any problem with code. Maybe you have problems with dependencies [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62482475/android-room-error-fields-annotated-with-relation-must-be-a-list-or-set)

Comment: Changing the dependencies fixed the issue.Thanks for the valuable answer